# Localhost http error .NET MAUI, network_security_config not found

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

I am trying fetch a localhost API using .NET MAUI, so while following the official docs
( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services )

I have created and updated the network_security_config.xml and I have also update the AndroidManifest.xml file

**network_security_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

The file structure is :

[image]

Error :

[image]

Comment: You did not tell which problem you have. Any errors? Any questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I created a demo and could reproduce this problem on my side.

Please try to set the `Build Action` of file `network_security_config.xml` to `AndroidResource`.

[image]

And from the document [Android network security configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services#android-network-security-configuration) you shared, we could see the tip:

> Make sure the Build Action is set as `AndroidResource`, otherwise the
> XML file will not be found at build time.